# Visual Studio Pro 2008: Equivalent of Eclipse's member list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, eclipse, ide

In Eclipse, when you are viewing a class (such as Java), there is a window available to list all the fields and functions of that class. Is there an equivalent for Visual Studio 2008 Pro, for C# (XNA)?

(I'm looking for an easy way to locate and jump between functions. Is there a better way to do this in VS?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: View + Object Browser.  Click around a bit more to discover these kind of features by yourself, it's worth your time.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the class browser in Visual Studio.

Go to **View** -> **Class View**

Answer (score 1):

If you have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) try ReSharper->Windows->File Structure Window

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Object Browser. Click View-Object Browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Source Code Outliner Power Toy](http://www.codeplex.com/SourceCodeOutliner).

[image: Source Code Outliner Power Toy]
<sub>(source: [280z28.org](http://www.280z28.org/images/vsx/SourceOutliner.png))</sub>